# Counting RF packet loss with interference, parsing with Python

Tags: python, packet

I'm parsing, with Python, data files from RF sensors that save packets with sequence numbers and time stamps.  I need to count for lost packets and ignore packets from interference (packets out of sequence).

How it works:

- Packet sequence ranges from 0-255 and rolls over.
- First packet sent to sensors always is numbered 0.  (Doesn't mean first packet in data file is always 0.)
- Interference packets are out of sequence and can be random, also from 0-255.
- Packets are sent to the sensors every 5 ms.  (Sensors sometimes record a packet with a 6ms time delta.)

A packet found out of sequence in the data file might be an interference packet, but can also exist because of a missing packet.  So far, I'm only checking if the "previous" packet has a difference >1.  What's a clever way to differentiate lost packets and interference packets?

```
for fname in glob(path.join(fdir, 'RFsensor*.txt')):
    with open(fname,'r') as fin:
        dump = fin.readlines()
        fin.close()

        ## Tracks line indices when RF channel changes
        lastchan = dump[8][53:55]
        channels = [int(lastchan,16)]
        startindex = [0]
        endindex = []
        for i,line in enumerate(dump[8:]):
            if line[53:55] != lastchan:
                channels.append(int(line[53:55],16))
                startindex.append(i)
                endindex.append(i-1)
            lastchan = line[53:55]
        endindex.append(len(dump[8:])-1)

        ## Calculate data and write results according to line index values
        count = 0
        lost = 0
        for i,line in enumerate(dump[8:]):
            count+=1
            PktSeq = int(line[42:44],16)
            ## Check i against startindex
            if startindex and i == startindex[0]:
                stamp = TestStamp(line)
                stamp = '%s:%s:%s' % (stamp[11:13],stamp[14:16],stamp[17:19])
                chan = int(line[53:55],16)
                startindex.pop(0)
            ## Check for lost packets
            else:
                diff = PktSeq - prevSeq - 1
                ## Account for sequence roll over
                if PktSeq < prevSeq:
                    diff = diff + 256
                if diff != 0:
                    lost += diff
            prevSeq = PktSeq
```

Comment: The format seems ambiguous. How do you distinguish a sequence `P1 P2 P3` from `P1 I2 P3` (`P` — packet, `I` — interference packet, `\d` — sequence number) that have consecutive timestamps?

Comment: Yep, that's what I need help with.  I forgot to mention (I'll edit my post), the packets are sent every 5ms.  But I've seen 6ms as well.  So I'm thinking about checking for the time delta first (to rule out interference packets) and then the sequence (to count lost packets).